# MatrixPower with Modulus

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, modular-arithmetic

I have a matrix that will be multiplied with itself by an extremely large amount of times under $Z/pZ$. The matrix itself contains small numbers, so `MatrixPower[Mod[mat, p], pow, vec]` won't work; and taking $\bmod$ after calculation is infeasible since the result is extremely large. Can I have similar functionality like some other function's `Modulus -> p` with `MatrixPower`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using an *undocumented* function:

```
Algebra`MatrixPowerMod[{{2, 3, 1}, {5, 2, 4}, {0, 3, 2}}, 4, 6]
```

> ```
> {{1, 0, 5}, {1, 1, 5}, {3, 3, 4}}
> ```

```
Mod[MatrixPower[{{2, 3, 1}, {5, 2, 4}, {0, 3, 2}}, 4], 6]
```

> ```
> {{1, 0, 5}, {1, 1, 5}, {3, 3, 4}}
> ```

Unfortunately, the undocumented function does not support the action form of `MatrixPower[]`.

Comment: This is exactly what I want, PE502 part 2 solved:)

Comment: Another one for [(805)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/805/121).  @happyfish There are over 500 PE problems now?  That's a lot to work through!  I stopped when there were only 330 or so, and I was getting repeatedly stumped by ones in the 130's.  How many have you solved?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I have done nearly 200, most of them are simple ones. But 502 is on the top of their difficulty list and I am nearly done :)

Comment: This function also support negative exponent (modular inverse).

Answer (score 5):

Bressoud & Wagon define `MatrixPowerMod` on page 34 of their book, *A Course in Computational Number Theory*.

```
MatrixPowerMod[a_, n_, m_] :=
   Block[{b = a, d = IntegerDigits[n, 2]},
         Do[
            b = Mod[b.b, m];
            If[d[[i]] == 1, b = Mod[b.a, m]],
            {i, 2, Length[d]}];
         b]
```

An example involving Fibonacci numbers is the following:

```
AbsoluteTiming[MatrixPowerMod[{{0, 1}, {1, 1}}, 10^8, 10^10]]
(* {0.005576, {{1300390626, 7760546875}, {7760546875, 9060937501}}} *)
```

Comment: This is, of course, the "Russian peasant" algorithm for exponentiation. Here is a compact implementation: `Fold[Mod[If[#2 == 1, a.#, #].#, m] &, a, Rest[IntegerDigits[n, 2]]]`.