# A modular version of LinearRecurrence?

Tags: number-theory, difference-equations, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

I'm playing around with implementing the Lucas probable prime test (mainly so I can understand it better), and would love a version of the LinearRecurrence function that used addition modulo n (with n supplied by the user) instead of ordinary addition (which can easily result in overflows).

It wouldn't be all that crazy-hard to implement one, I think, and might even be quite interesting to do, but I thought I'd ask whether anyone already knows of such a thing.

Comment: A concrete example, with input and desired output, would be useful here.

Comment: There isn't a built-in function, but you might be interested in the *undocumented* function [``Algebra`MatrixPowerMod[]``](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/123241), which might help in your implementation.

Comment: Oh, wow--I think that's almost certainly going to do the trick. Thanks so much!

Comment: p = NextPrime[10^100]; Mod[(Algebra`MatrixPowerMod[{{0, 1}, {1, 1}}, p -2 - JacobiSymbol[p, 5], p].{1, 1})[[2]], p] returns 0, very quickly; exactly what I was trying to do. That's Fibonacci; adapting to other recurrence relations will be a breeze. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You can build your own "LinearRecurrence" and then use any function you like. Here is an example from MMA help:

```
LinearRecurrence[{a, b}, {1, 1}, 5]
```

this gives:

```
{1, 1, a + b, b + a (a + b), b (a + b) + a (b + a (a + b))}
```

We can do the same by:

```
Reap[Nest[(Sow[t = #.{b, a}]; {#[[2]], t}) &, {1, 1}, 3] ]
```

To introduce Mod, you would write:

```
Reap[Nest[(Sow[t =Mod[ #.{b, a},n]; {#[[2]], t}) &, {1, 1}, 3] ]
```

Comment: Your answer might be improved for the OP & future users if you can link to the “MMA help” page you pull this from.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this! I realise I need to clarify.

The thing is, my guess is that LinearRecurrence uses some clever stuff to cope with large n, probably based on repeated doubling of the index. My n will be large, so my programming task would involve duplicating that clever stuff, rather than simply nesting (n-2) times. That's doable, but I wondered if anyone had already done it.

Comment: So for example

`LinearRecurrenceMod[{1,1},{1,1},10^100+1,10^100]`

would return the googol-plus-oneth Fibonacci number, reduced mod googol.

Kind of like a LinearRecurrence version of PowerMod, if you take my meaning.

Comment: (At least, it's doable for second order recurrence relations, via Lucas U and V sequences; not sure if that generalises; number theory's not really my comfort zone.)